# Using history.pushState with the pageShow and similar events

Tags: javascript

Bit of background in the problem: I am working on a project that loads most of it's content via api calls in JS. The initial page is built in PHP and delivered ready to use, but every interaction/load after that is just done in JS async and pushed to the "content area" of the html. I'm adding QoL so that you can navigate back to where you were using your history/back/forward button, but in order to do that, every time you navigate using those buttons, I would like to force-refresh the page (for various reasons which I don't think are relevant but am happy to describe if requested).

I'm struggling to understand both pushState and pageShow when used in conjunction. As far as I know, I can use pushState to push new entries to the history object every time it's run, like so:

```
// Update history
var stateObj = {};
history.pushState(stateObj, response.data.title, uri);
```

That seems to be working when I run that section of code and check my browser history; a nice neat entry sitting there every time I run it. As far as I know, the title isn't actually supported by any browser, but it doesn't hurt to have it.

My issue occurs when I try to use that newly generated history with the back/forward buttons. As far as I can tell doing some google research, typical browser behavior will not actually reload the page when I press the back button. Herein is where I believe my problem occurs. While navigating to any url fresh will load that specific piece of content into the content area, the site is basically a single page application, loading content into the content area async as it needs it. It doesn't actually change pages. I'm not sure, but I think that is the core problem. I have tried to use several events to "catch" the back/forward behavior:

```
window.onunload

window.onpageshow

$(window).on("pagehide", function() {}) 

window.addEventListener("pageshow", function(event) {})
```

I know several of those are basically the same thing, but I was trying to cover my bases. I have looked around for a solution, and I know that **window.onunload** is **SUPPOSED** to override the bfcache (not even sure if that is my problem), but it doesn't seem to fire at all, no matter how many times I navigate between the history.pushState entries. I'm not familiar enough with any of these functions to tell where my problem is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the `onpopstate` event? A quick search found [history.pushstate fails browser back and forward button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22751023/215552)...

Comment: I genuinely don't know where you found that but you just saved me what I'm sure would be several hours of trying other stuff. Thanks man.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [history.pushstate fails browser back and forward button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751023/history-pushstate-fails-browser-back-and-forward-button)